# Select column name where value = 1 in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
    Course_2013     AP  Advanced    Vocational  Basic   ESL 
0   7th Math Enrich  0    1             0         0      0   
1   8th Math Enrich  0    1             0         0      0   
2   8th Science Enr  0    1             0         0      0   
3   Accounting I     0    0             0         1      0               
4   Accounting II    0    0             0         0      1
```

I need to create new column named "category" that contains columns name for the column in each row that contains 1:

```
    Course_2013     AP  Advanced    Vocational  Basic   ESL category
0   7th Math Enrich  0    1             0         0      0   Advanced
1   8th Math Enrich  0    1             0         0      0   Advanced
2   8th Science Enr  0    1             0         0      0   Advanced
3   Accounting I     0    0             0         1      0   Basic              
4   Accounting II    0    0             0         0      1   ESL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use `apply` and `idxmax`:

```
df['category'] = df.iloc[:,1:].apply(lambda x: x.idxmax(), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
       Course_2013  AP  Advanced  Vocational  Basic  ESL  category
0  7th Math Enrich   0         1           0      0    0  Advanced
1  8th Math Enrich   0         1           0      0    0  Advanced
2  8th Science Enr   0         1           0      0    0  Advanced
3     Accounting I   0         0           0      1    0     Basic
4    Accounting II   0         0           0      0    1       ESL
```